# Self-invoking function and "use strict" and default parameter

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically **warp** some **unknown code** in an anonymous function and pass some parameters to it. e.g.

```js
((win, a, b = a.info) => { 
  
  /* unknown code
  *  unknown code
  *  unknown code
  */
  
})(window, {info: {/*....*/}});
```

Above works fine but if the **unknown code** starts with `"use strict"` there will an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: "use strict" not allowed in function with default parameter

Defining the variable inside the function would void `"use strict"`, if present. e.g.

```js
((win, a) => { const b = a.info;
  
  /* unknown code
  *  unknown code
  *  unknown code
  */
  
})(window, {info: {/*....*/}});
```

I can pass the parameter again but it is large and feels like a waste e.g.

```js
((win, a, b) => { 

  /* unknown code
  *  unknown code
  *  unknown code
  */

})(window, {info: {/*....*/}}, {/*....*/});
```

Is there any other/better way to achieve the desired result?

#### Update: a possibility

It seems double wrapping in IIFE can solve the issue, although a bit ugly (but still much shorter than passing the variable twice).

```js
((win, a, b = a.info) => { 
(() => {

  /* unknown code
  *  unknown code
  *  unknown code
  */
  
})();
})(window, {info: {/*....*/}});
```

Comment: "Defining the variable inside the function would void "use strict", if present."

What do you mean by this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Strict_Non_Simple_Params

Comment: @Alex `function run(){"use strict"; a = 5;} run();` `// Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable a` but `function run(){const b = 10; "use strict"; a = 5;} run();` `// no error`. That voids `"use strict"` since `"use strict"` has to be declared first in the function.

Comment: @erosman I see, can you elaborate on how the unknown code is getting "inserted" into the function? Is it possible for you to modify it or e.g. detect "use strict" before using the code? Also, for your 3rd option, you can get rid of the copy/paste by storing the parameter in a variable before passing it in.

Comment: Code is from users e.g. dynamic code and inserted by a Firefox add-on. Detecting `"use strict"` is not foolproof and then even when detected, wont solve the issue. Altering the unknown code is not desired. Storing variables OUTSIDE IIFE would expose them to `page` context and not desired. That is the main purpose of using the IIFE to keep those variables accessible within IIFE only.